# Почему не отображается уведомление

Tags: java, android

Не могу понять почему не отображается уведомление:

```
    System.out.println("Start!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "Channel")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.five)
                    .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                    .setContentText("Пора покормить кота")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(189, builder.build());
    System.out.println("Start9!9!9!9!9!9!9!9!9!9!9!9!9!9!9!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
```

Comment: На какой версии ОС запускаете? Если после, вроде 7, то канал надо явно создать, просто строкой названия ограничиться не выйдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать канал вместо строки Channel